# I keep getting a blank page on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

i have the recent macbook air and i installed Xampp 7.4.29-1. when i tried connecting php with mysql the phpmyadmin page shows blank. please help me if anyone knows how to resolve it? i tried changing the display_errors to on in the php.ini file but it still shows bank

Comment: Check your webserver log(s) to see what the error may be.

Comment: "Blank page" usually translates to "error during rendering" which means you need to find and inspect your server's error logs.